# How to assert that Set contains the required values with should.js?

Tags: node.js, set, should.js

I am using the [should.js](https://shouldjs.github.io/) library for assertions in my unit tests and was wondering how I would go about asserting that the contents of a `Set` matches the expectation.

```
let actualValues = new Set();
actualValues.add(2);
actualValues.add(4);
actualValues.add(6);

actualValues.should.be....... ?
```

My first instinct was to use `Array.from(actualValues)` and then compare that with the expected values; but naturally the ordering of `actualValues` is undefined since it's a `Set`.

The following works; but it seems quite verbose:

```
actualValues.size.should.be.eql(3);
actualValues.has(2).should.be.true();
actualValues.has(4).should.be.true();
actualValues.has(6).should.be.true();
```

Comment: This is good feature request. Best you can do convert set to array and use containDeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over one set and assert each item is also in the second set, then assert their sizes are equal.

```
const should = require('should')

const set1 = new Set(['red', 'green', 'blue']);
const set2 = new Set(['blue', 'red', 'green']);
for (let x of set1) {
  set2.has(x).should.be.true()
}
set2.size.should.equal(set1.size)
```

This might be a good candidate for at least a helper function like `haveSameContent(set1, set2)` which you may also be able to code into a `should.js` extension if you want to be able to do something like `set1.should.have.same.items.as(set2)`.

Comment: Seems like `should.equal(set1, set2)` or `should.deepEqual(set1, set2)` would do the job.

Comment: @Nuclearman I just tested and `should.equal(set1, set2)` does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: It could be just set1.should.eql(set2) if it does not work, it is a bug.